# How to convert a String into an SortedMap<String,SortedMap<String,Object>>?

Tags: java

I have a situation were I want to convert a string into an `SortedMap<String,SortedMap<String,Object>>`. In my string can have an number of word which I want to be added into an sorted Map.

```
String s2="{ age={},  city={City=1.4054651},  phoneno={},  zip={Zip=0.30685282}, name={}}";
```

please help me.

Comment: yes,is like a true toString() from a Map,because i am using Rabbitmq publisher class that send message into byte[], when consumer get the message it again return byte[].i am typecast bytes array into string, again i need to typecast string value into sortmap.

Comment: Are the values always numbers, or could they be `String`s or other objects as well? If it's only numbers, it shouldn't be too hard, but if `String`s are also allowed, you get nasty stuff as: `city={City="}}}"}` (the string containing `}`).

Comment: yes i tried but in last i stuck followingg code

Comment: String s2="{ age={},  city={City=1.4054651},  phoneno={},  zip={Zip=0.30685282}, name={}}";
         System.out.println(s2);
         int length = s2.length();
         int size=length-1;
         if(s2.charAt(0)=='{' && s2.charAt(size)=='}')
         {
            String substring = s2.substring(1,length-1);
            System.out.println(substring);
            String[] split = substring.split(",");
         }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3370/discussion-between-sam-and-bart-kiers)

Comment: No chat for me. Please edit your original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public  static HashMap stringToHashMap(String str)
    {
        int count=0;
        int equal_index=0;
        int commaindex=0;
        String key=null,val=null;
        HashMap map=new HashMap();
        int size=str.length();
        if(str.charAt(0)=='{' && str.charAt(size-1)=='}')
        {
        System.out.println("Valid-Map object");
        str=str.substring(1);
        size=size-1;
        while(size!=0)
        {
            equal_index=str.indexOf('=');
            if(equal_index==-1 && count==0)
                return null;
            key=str.substring(0,equal_index);
            str=str.substring(key.length()+1,size);
            size=size-(key.length()+1);

            commaindex=str.indexOf(",");
            if(commaindex==-1)
                commaindex=str.lastIndexOf('}');
            val=str.substring(0,commaindex);
            str=str.substring(val.length()+1,size);
            size=size-(val.length()+1);
            key=key.trim();
            val.trim();
            map.put(key, val);
            count++;
        }
        }
        else
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid string format--Cannot convert it to map");
            return map;
    }
```